# Convert object to json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How should I convert into this format

```
    {"Campaign Technical Approach Plan": "PM",  
  "Campaign Monitoring": "India",   
  "Email HTML Build": "India",  
  "Email Quality Assurance": "India"}
```

from this format

```
    [[Campaign Technical Approach Plan,__PM__LOCATION__],   
  [Campaign Monitoring,India],  
  [Email HTML Build,India], 
  [Email Quality Assurance,India]]
```

Comment: You tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried JSON.stringyfy(). But that doesn't work.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will convert a JSON object to string, but your requirement is different.

Comment: Is the `[[]]` entity a string literal, or an array of strings that are missing their quote delimiters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. Just iterate over list to build your object.

```js
var input = [["Campaign Technical Approach Plan","__PM__LOCATION__"],   
  ["Campaign Monitoring","India"],  
  ["Email HTML Build","India"], 
  ["Email Quality Assurance","India"]];

var obj = {};

input.forEach(function(item){
  obj[item[0]] = item[1].replace(/_|LOCATION/g, "");
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: output is like this   {Campaign Execution (Minimum)=PM, Localization process management (0-5)=India, Email Quality Assurance (Minimum)=India}                       not the exact one.

Comment: @Neetu So not the JSON object ?

Comment: I want output like this.

Comment: {"Campaign Technical Approach Plan": "PM",  
  "Campaign Monitoring": "India",   
  "Email HTML Build": "India",  
  "Email Quality Assurance": "India"}

Comment: @Neetu Yes, you can see the same in log after running above snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert data array to object using `Array.prototype.reduce`. Then use `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
let data =  [
 ['Campaign Technical Approach Plan','__PM__LOCATION__'],   
   ['Campaign Monitoring','India'],  
   ['Email HTML Build','India'], 
   ['Email Quality Assurance','India']
];


let result = JSON.stringify(data.reduce((resultObj, [ key, value ]) => { 
 resultObj[key] = value
 return resultObj;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=b).

Code:

```js
const arr = [['Campaign Technical Approach Plan', '__PM__LOCATION__'],['Campaign Monitoring', 'India'],['Email HTML Build', 'India'],['Email Quality Assurance', 'India']];
const result = arr.reduce(function (a, c) {
  a[c[0]] = c[1].replace(/_|LOCATION/g, '');
  return a; 
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple.

```
var object =  {"Campaign Technical Approach Plan": "PM",  
  "Campaign Monitoring": "India",   
  "Email HTML Build": "India",  
  "Email Quality Assurance": "India"}

var JSON = JSON.stringify(object); //Converted to JSON
```

To do the opposite (JSON to JS object) use JSON.parse()